# Does sequence converge if its differences become strictly monotonously greater?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the following sequence:
$(x_n) = x_1, x_2, ...$

Now, let's say this particular sequence has this property: $x_{n + 1} - x_n > 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$  Then we say that this sequence grows. It' certanily possible that this sequence converges (take, for example, sequence $x_1, x_1 + 0.1, x_1 + 0.01, ...$, we see that $n$-th term is obviously $x_1 + 111...1$ which is obviously some real number).

But add another property of this sequence; let' also say that differences $x_2 - x_1, x_3 - x_2, ...$ make another strictly growing sequence, in other words $x_{n + 1} - x_n > x_{m + 1} - x_m$ for every $n$ such that $n > m$ (it's like positive 2nd derivative in a way).

My intuition tells me that then $(x_n)$ cannot converge. If true, how to prove this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you know about Cauchy sequences?

Comment: Exatcly nothing...

Comment: That's fine. Look at things this way: if $(x_n)$ converges (to a finite value) what can you say about $x_n-x_m$ for large $n$ and $m$?

Comment: Or more directly, what would the sequence $(x_{n+1}-x_n)$ converge to?

Comment: $x_n - x_m$ will, at some point, be smaller and smaller (when $n, m, n > m$ are close enough)?

Comment: $x_{n + 1} - x_n$ will eventually go to $0$ I think

Comment: Nice, can you provide me by more rigorous proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is simple. $x_n$ converges if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an index $N > 0$ such that $|x_p-x_q| < \epsilon$ for every $p, q > N$. In particular setting $p = q+1$ yields the necessary condition $|x_{q+1}-x_q| < \epsilon$ for every $q > N$.

(You really don't need Cauchy sequences here. Just notice that if a sequence $x_n$ has to converge, then obviously $x_{n+1}-x_n \to 0$).

You are requiring $x_{n+1}-x_n > x_{m+1}-x_m > 0$ for some $m$ and all $n > m$. Now if you set $\epsilon = x_{m+1}-x_m > 0$, the necessary condition is not satisfied, no matter how you choose $N$ large.